# Trouble manipulating quotients in $\mathbb{N}^\times$

Tags: divisibility, natural-numbers

As part of a proof about multinomial expansions, I am encountering difficulty in showing the following equality:
$$\frac{k!}{\alpha!} = \frac{(k-\alpha_1)!}{\alpha'!}\frac{k!}{\alpha_1!(k - \alpha_1)!},$$
where $k \in \mathbb{N}^\times$, $\alpha = (\alpha_1, ...,\alpha_{m+1}) \in \mathbb{N}^{m+1}$ for some $m \geq 2$, $\alpha' = (\alpha_2, ...,\alpha_{m+1})$, and where factorials of multinomial indices are defined as products of the factorials of their entries. I emphasize that I do not know a priori that $\alpha!$ even divides $k!$. I am hoping someone can show me the argument for this equality which will, in the end, by definition of quotients in the natural numbers result in the proof of the fact that
$$k! = \left[\frac{(k-\alpha_1)!}{\alpha'!}\frac{k!}{\alpha_1!(k - \alpha_1)!} \right]\alpha!,$$
which will be enough by the uniqueness of quotients.

However, given that we are in $\mathbb{N}$ and not in $\mathbb{Q}$, I cannot just naively move things around in the numerator and denominator.

For context, I have supplied the proof which (at the end) has me stumped:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We seem to be working in a context in which $\mathbb{Q}$ has not been defined, so it's forbidden to mention quotients where the denominator does not divide the numerator. The usual algebraic laws though still hold whenever the quotients exist (as elements of $\mathbb{Z}$).

The screenshotted argument says it's an inductive proof; the part you're concerned with is the implication from case $m$ to case $m+1$.
Here $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_{m+1})$, $\alpha'=(\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_{m+1})$, and $k=\sum_{i=1}^{m+1}\alpha_i$.
Note that $k-\alpha_1=\sum_{i=2}^{m+1}\alpha_i$ is the length of $\alpha'$. So case $m$ applies to the multi-index $\alpha'$, asserting that
$$\frac{(k-\alpha_1)!}{\alpha'!}$$
is an element of $\mathbb{N}$.

So the product
$$\frac{(k-\alpha_1)!}{\alpha'!}\binom{k}{\alpha_1}\in\mathbb{N}.$$
The text seems to have already established the formula for the binomial coefficient, so we're entitled to write
$$\frac{(k-\alpha_1)!}{\alpha'!}\frac{k!}{(k-\alpha_1)!\alpha_1!}$$
for this product. Now as I said, the usual rules hold for quotients provided they all belong to $\mathbb{Z}$, so we can combine the product into one quotient and cancel the $(k-\alpha_1)!$. Since $\alpha!=\alpha_1!\alpha'!$ (just by writing out what these multi-index factorial symbols mean), this concludes the induction.

If you want a proof that
$$\frac{A}{B}\frac{C}{D}=\frac{AC}{BD}$$
in $\mathbb{Z}$, in the sense that if the left side is well-defined, so is the right and then they are equal, that's not hard to do. Just write
$$\begin{align}\frac{A}{B}=X&\Leftrightarrow A=BX\\
\frac{C}{D}=Y&\Leftrightarrow C=DY\\
\frac{AC}{BD}=XY&\Leftrightarrow AC=BDXY
\end{align}$$
To be more explicit, if the left-hand-sides of the first two equations hold, then the right-hand-sides hold, and those RHS's imply the RHS of the third equation which then imply the LHS.

However, it doesn't work in the reverse direction. Easy counter-example: $\frac{1\cdot 2}{2\cdot 1}$ is an integer, but $\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{1}$ is a fraction times an integer.

Likewise it's easy to show that
$$\frac{CA}{CB}=\frac{A}{B}$$
if $C\neq0$, in the sense that if one side is well-defined in $\mathbb{Z}$ then so is the other, and then they are equal.

Comment: Sorry, I should be clearer in my OP: this argument is taking place in $\mathbb{N}$ with no knowledge of $\mathbb{Q}$! We have not constructed $\mathbb{Q}$ yet even. It's for that reason that I'm a bit concerned with this notion of "cancellation". I am hoping for an answer which *only* uses properties of $\mathbb{N}$, so perhaps I have not understood yours here?

Comment: OK, I rewrote the answer completely.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I get home I am going to check that this gets me to understand the proof, so I’ll hold off accepting until then just so I don’t bother you again. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Got it, just wrote them out myself and follow. If you have any other sources on when these lemmas hold, then I'd greatly appreciate it (but no worries if not). I wrote them out as being valid assuming one side was valid but would wonder about the other: (1) If $\frac{A}{B}\frac{C}{D}$ exists (i.e. if $B$ divides $A$ and $D$ divides $C$) then $BD$ divides $AC$ and, in particular, $$\frac{AC}{BD} = \frac{A}{B}\frac{C}{D}.$$ (2) If $\frac{CA}{CB}$ exists (i.e. if $CB$ divides $CA$ ) then, if $C \neq 0$, $B$ divides $A$ and, in particular, 
        $$\frac{AC}{BC} = \frac{A}{B}.$$

Comment: I don't know any text that proves these equations for $\mathbb{Z}$, but they're easy enough to derive.

Comment: Frankly, I don't understand what's going on in your textbook. It seems very odd to me to be trying to prove the multinomial formula under the restriction that $\mathbb{Q}$ must not be mentioned. A textbook like the classic Landau, *Foundations of Analysis*, or other books that go through the construction of $\mathbb{Q}$ from $\mathbb{Z}$  don't try to do number theory or combinatorics under that restriction. It seems like a weird mashup of two different topics. What textbook does the screenshot come from?

Comment: This is Amann and Escher *Analysis I*, in the algebraic preliminaries (Chapter 8). If you have any suggestions I'd be greatly appreciative.

Comment: Not familiar with that analysis book. It maybe fine for that. But I don’t see the point in avoiding $\mathbb{Q}$. Just my opinion.

Comment: That's well taken. Thanks agin for your help Michael!